# Semantic UI bottom sidebar with always visible button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Trying to implement a Sidebar from Semantic UI http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/definition, that comes from the bottom, but it doesn't fully hides, leaving a "strip" button that allows you to reopen it.

This is the best as I got : https://jsfiddle.net/wcec9gc6/1/

html :

```
<div class="ui bottom sidebar">Sidebar Content</div>
<div class="pusher">Page content</div>
<div class="ui bottom fixed menu button">
Click to open sidebar</div>
```

But as you can see it does not pushes the fixed button up, but I also don't want it to push the rest of the page, only the button

Comment: This is exactly what I have been struggling with this week. If i find anything i'll come back and post about it.. My Pen: [See Bottom for Button](http://codepen.io/DarrenfJ/full/vgzoGy/)

Comment: @DarrenJoy I used a sort of ghetto solution, have the button div fixed at the top of the sidebar and use translate to bring it outside